# Transmitir imagem de uma câmera ip via streaming (FFmpeg)

Tags: streaming, vídeo

Tenho uma aplicação escrita em Node.Js que precisa gravar o vídeo da câmera em um arquiivo mp4 e também transmití-lo via streaming para uma url específica. Para fins de teste e de aprendizado, fiz um código utilizando a webcam do notebook como entrada de dados, porém, gostaria de saber como alterar o código original que está funcionando perfeitamente para usar uma câmera IP como entrada de dados.

**Protocolo RTMP resolveria o problema?**

**Código:**

```
ffmpeg -f dshow -rtbufsize 2048M -i video="Integrated Webcam" -t 300 -codec:v mpeg1video 
meuvideo.mp4 -f mpegts -q:v 5 -codec:v mpeg1video -t 300 http://127.0.0.1:4000/token
```

Answer (score 2):

Você precisa verificar nas especificações da sua câmera IP quais os formatos/protocolos de saída ela trabalha. O ffmpeg funciona tanto com RTMP quanto com TCP/UDP de entrada, então vai depender mesmo dais capacidades da sua câmera.

Entrada em UDP:

```
ffmpeg -i udp://localhost:1234 -codec:v mpeg1video meuvideo.mp4 -f mpegts -q:v 5 -codec:v mpeg1video -t 300 http://127.0.0.1:4000/token
```

Entrada em RTMP:

```
ffmpeg -i rtmp://localhost:1234/meuStream -codec:v mpeg1video meuvideo.mp4 -f mpegts -q:v 5 -codec:v mpeg1video -t 300 http://127.0.0.1:4000/token
```